# DataGridView - display date in "Short Format" without casting to string

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview

I take only date from a `DateTimePicker` (using `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date`) and I put it into a cell of a `DataGridView`.

Cell is displaing someting like

> 07/07/2016 00:00:00

I would like to display only date (07/07/2016) **without changing data type to string**.

I tried with

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Date").DefaultCellStyle.Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

but doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Date").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Date").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"
```